# How to make type alias invisible to derived classes?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp, type-alias, class-template

I have a set of base graph classes that use `CRTP` to work with the derived graph classes. I have a template class `GraphTypes` that take the derived graph classes as template parameters, and then the base graph classes, like `Edge` and `Node`, take `GraphTypes` as template parameter.

Inside the base `graph` classes, I use type aliases (`using`) to simplify using the derived classes. I would like these type aliases to only be visible inside the base graph classes, and not in the derived graph classes. Is this possible?

See the code below for the setup, and an issue where the type alias in the base graph class is being used in the derived class.

```cpp
namespace DirectedGraph 
{
    template<class NodeT, class EdgeT>
    class GraphTypes 
    {
    public:
        using NodeType = NodeT;
        using EdgeType = EdgeT;
    };

    template<class GraphTypes>
    class Edge 
    {
    private:
        using NodeType = typename GraphTypes::NodeType;
        using EdgeType = typename GraphTypes::EdgeType;
    public:
        auto This() -> EdgeType&;
    };
}

namespace MyGraph
{
    class Node;
    class Edge;
    using GraphTypes = DirectedGraph::GraphTypes<Node, Edge>;

    enum class EdgeType { A, B, C };

    class Edge : public DirectedGraph::Edge<GraphTypes>
    {
        Edge(EdgeType Type); // `EdgeType` is interpreted as the type alias `DirectedGraph::Edge::EdgeType` instead of the enum `MyGraph::EdgeType`.
    };
}
```

Comment: It will not answer your question but I'm counting 3 different meanings for `GraphTypes`. It might be legal, but it is confusing (at least for me).
Using different names may help to clarify the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you don't want to rename `EdgeType` in `Edge`. If you were willing to do that, you could just use different names for different aliases and not run into this issue.

To solve this issue without changing any names, you can shadow `DirectedGraph::Edge<T>::EdgeType` by declaring another alias inside of `MyGraph::Edge`:

```cpp
class Edge : public DirectedGraph::Edge<GraphTypes> {
    // possibly make this private
    using EdgeType = MyGraph::EdgeType;

    // we could also use MyGraph::EdgeType directly here, but that would be uglier
    Edge(EdgeType Type);
};
```

The `MyGraph::Edge::EdgeType` alias will shadow any declarations in the scope of the base class and in the surrounding scope, so you can disambiguate like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can always qualify the full namespace

```
namespace MyGraph {
    class Node;
    class Edge;
    using GraphTypes = DirectedGraph::GraphTypes<Node, Edge>;

    enum class EdgeType { A, B, C };

    class Edge : public DirectedGraph::Edge<GraphTypes> {
        Edge(::MyGraph::EdgeType Type);
        //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // or
        // Edge(MyGraph::EdgeType Type);
    };
}
```

Or use different names for types/ type aliases for avoiding confusion.

---

That being said, if you insist on keeping the names as it is, and do not want to use them from the base class, provide an indirection to those alias types, by a class/struct.

```
namespace DirectedGraph 
{
    // ....

    template<class GraphTypes>
    class Edge {
    private:
    public:
        struct Internal { // moved under the Internal struct!
            using NodeType = typename GraphTypes::NodeType;
            using EdgeType = typename GraphTypes::EdgeType;
        };

        auto This() -> typename Internal::EdgeType&;
    };
}

namespace MyGraph {
    // ....
    enum class EdgeType { A, B, C };

    class Edge : public DirectedGraph::Edge<GraphTypes> {
        Edge(EdgeType Type); //Now you can!
    };
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hdE8qWsKn)